# How to delete a line of text file

Tags: c#, .net

There is a file (`E:\sample.txt`) like this:

```
Indian 
English
Spanish
French
English
Spanish
English
Polish
French
```

Now I want to write a windows application (C# language ) to search this file for the word `English` and delete the line if it exists. If not exits send a message to user with `not found`.

As you can see it's possible to have more than one line containing the word `English` and i want to delete all those lines and make the line 'NULL'.

- I won't import everything on one string or array

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in `winform`. `textbox1` is where you enter your word and `textbox2` will display the message.

```
textBox2.Clear();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
    string LinesToDelete = textBox1.Text;
    var Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\sample.txt");
    if (Lines.Contains(textBox1.Text))
    {
        var newLines = Lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(LinesToDelete));
        File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\sample.txt", newLines);
        textBox2.Text = "Removed";
    }

    else
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Not found";
    }
}
```

If you do not need to show the message, the code below will be sufficient.

```
var Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\sample.txt");
var newLines = Lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(LinesToDelete));
File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\sample.txt", newLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really delete lines from a file. What you  need to do is to overwrite the file with the unwanted lines with a new file that does not have the unwanted lines

```
static void DeleteLines(string filename, string searchText) {
    bool searchTextFound = false;

    // Obtain the filtered lines
    var filteredLines = File.ReadLines(filename).Where(line => !(searchTextFound = line.Contains(searchText)) /* You can use case insensitive match, regex matching, etc here */ );

    if (searchTextFound) {
        // Create a temp file to store the filtered lines. You can do it in memory, if you know that the file is small
        string destFilename = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllLines(destFilename, filteredLines);

        // Now overwrite the original file with the filtered lines
        File.Delete(filename);
        File.Move(destFilename, filename);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine($"Search Text '{searchText}' not found");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    DeleteLines("Test.txt", "English");
}
```

Comment: Is this Console application? I need it for windows form :/

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static class FileHelper {
    public static int RemoveLines(string path, Predicate<string> remove) {
        var removed = 0;
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        using (var output = new StreamWriter(path)) {
            foreach (var line in lines) {
                if (remove(line)) {
                    removed++;
                } else {
                    output.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }
}
```

The RemoveLines function rewrites a file by "removing" specific lines and it returns the number of "removed" lines. In your case you can use:

```
if (FileHelper.RemoveLines("E:\\sample.txt", (l) => { return l = "English"; }) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("not found.");
```